# How do I make a score counter for my game in python?

Tags: python

Hi my friends helped me program this game in python. But I am wanting to add a score counter to my program - the score counter will keep track of how many times a user loses and wins.
If you guys can tell me how to add a score on my game or show me how I would really appreciate it. I do know that the score counter should be part of my main function but I am just not sure how to add a score counter, hence I am here.

I am using PYTHON VERSION 2.7.6
Total beginner in programing just began a few months ago :D
Thanks and here is my code:

```
import random 



def chkValidInput (userInput):

    chkNumber = False 


    for amtChar in range(0, len( userInput ) ):


        for aNumber in range(0, 10):

            if userInput[amtChar] == str(aNumber):
                chkNumber = True
                break
            elif userInput[amtChar] != str(aNumber):
                chkNumber = False

        if chkNumber == False:
            return False


    return True


def evaluateBet(choice):




    randNum = 0

    randNum = random.randrange(1,14)

    print "The random number is: " + str(randNum)

    if choice == "high" and randNum > 7:
        print "You Win!"
        return True               
    elif choice == "low" and randNum < 7:
        print "You Win!"
        return True
    else: 
        print "You Lose!"
        return False



def main():



    print "Commencing HiLo.py...\n"


    random.seed(None)


    points = 1000
    wager = 0
    userInput = None
    programLoop = True 
    validInput = False


    while programLoop == True:


        print "Points remaining: " + str( points )


        wager = 0
        userInput = None
        validInput = False


        while validInput == False:
            userInput = raw_input("\nMake a wager: ")

            validInput = chkValidInput(userInput)

            if validInput == False:
                print "Invalid Input. It must be a positive Number. Try Again."

            elif validInput == True: 
                if int( userInput ) > points:
                   validInput = False
                    print "You don't have enough points to make that wager. Try Again."
                elif int( userInput ) == 0:
                    validInput = False
                    print "Your wager must be greater than 0. Try Again."

        wager = int (userInput)
        points = points - wager

        print "Points remaining: " + str( points )
        print "Wager: " + str( wager )


        validInput = False 

        while validInput == False:
            userInput = raw_input("\nPlace a bet: Either type 'High' or 'Low': ")
            userInput = userInput.lower() 
            if userInput == "high" or userInput == "low": 
                validInput = True
            else:
                 print "You may only choose to type from the options 'high' or 'low' "


        if evaluateBet(userInput) == True:
            points = ( points + (wager * 2) )
            wager = 0

        print "Points remaining: " + str( points )


        validInput = False 

        if points <= 0:
            print "You do not have anymore points; game over."
            programLoop = False
        else:
            while validInput == False:
                userInput = raw_input("\nWould you like to play again?: Type 'yes' or 'no': ")
                userInput = userInput.lower() 

                if userInput == "yes" or userInput == "no": 
                    validInput = True
                else:
                    print "You may only choose to type from the options 'yes' or 'no' "

            if userInput == "yes":
                programLoop = True
            elif userInput == "no":
                programLoop = False



main()
```

Comment: Add a variable named `win`, and then one named `lose`. And then increment them inside the win/lose `if statements`. ex. `win+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have almost all of the code necessary to make a score counter, just a few things you need to add in here and there.

Right under your `def main()` define the `wins` and `losses` variables both equal to 0

```
def main():
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
```

Under this line in the `main()` function

```
while programLoop == True:
```

put these print statements so the score can be printed out

```
print "Wins: " + str(wins)
print "Losses: " + str(losses)
```

Now change this if statement

```
if evaluateBet(userInput) == True:
    points = ( points + (wager * 2) )
    wager = 0
```

to

```
if evaluateBet(userInput) == True:
    points = ( points + (wager * 2) )
    wager = 0
    wins += 1
else:
    losses += 1
```

If you properly add in these lines of code you should now have a functional score counter.

One last thing, you have an indentation problem in your code.

```
elif validInput == True: 
                if int( userInput ) > points:
                   validInput = False
                    print "You don't have enough points to make that wager. Try Again."
```

Should be

```
elif validInput == True: 
                if int( userInput ) > points:
                    validInput = False
                    print "You don't have
```

enough points to make that wager. Try Again."

You just have to move `validInput = False` one space to the right.

**Edit: Full Code**

```
import random 

def chkValidInput (userInput):
    chkNumber = False 

    for amtChar in range(0, len( userInput ) ):
        for aNumber in range(0, 10):
            if userInput[amtChar] == str(aNumber):
                chkNumber = True
                break
            elif userInput[amtChar] != str(aNumber):
                chkNumber = False
        if chkNumber == False:
            return False

    return True


def evaluateBet(choice): 

    randNum = 0

    randNum = random.randrange(1,14)

    print "The random number is: " + str(randNum)

    if choice == "high" and randNum > 7:
        print "You Win!"
        return True               
    elif choice == "low" and randNum < 7:
        print "You Win!"
        return True
    else: 
        print "You Lose!"
        return False

def main():

    wins = 0 
    losses = 0

    print "Commencing HiLo.py...\n"

    random.seed(None)

    points = 1000
    wager = 0
    userInput = None
    programLoop = True 
    validInput = False

    while programLoop == True:

        print "Wins: " + str(wins)
        print "Losses: " + str(losses)

        print "Points remaining: " + str( points )

        wager = 0
        userInput = None
        validInput = False

        while validInput == False:
            userInput = raw_input("\nMake a wager: ")

            validInput = chkValidInput(userInput)

            if validInput == False:
                print "Invalid Input. It must be a positive Number. Try Again."

            elif validInput == True: 
                if int( userInput ) > points:
                    validInput = False
                    print "You don't have enough points to make that wager. Try Again."
                elif int( userInput ) == 0:
                    validInput = False
                    print "Your wager must be greater than 0. Try Again."

        wager = int (userInput)
        points = points - wager

        print "Points remaining: " + str( points )
        print "Wager: " + str( wager )

        validInput = False 

        while validInput == False:
            userInput = raw_input("\nPlace a bet: Either type 'High' or 'Low': ")
            userInput = userInput.lower() 
            if userInput == "high" or userInput == "low": 
                validInput = True
            else:
                 print "You may only choose to type from the options 'high' or 'low' "

        if evaluateBet(userInput) == True:
            points = ( points + (wager * 2) )
            wager = 0
            wins += 1
        else:
            losses += 1

        print "Points remaining: " + str( points )

        validInput = False 

        if points <= 0:
            print "You do not have anymore points; game over."
            programLoop = False
        else:
            while validInput == False:
                userInput = raw_input("\nWould you like to play again?: Type 'yes' or 'no': ")
                userInput = userInput.lower() 

                if userInput == "yes" or userInput == "no": 
                    validInput = True
                else:
                    print "You may only choose to type from the options 'yes' or 'no' "

            if userInput == "yes":
                programLoop = True
            elif userInput == "no":
                print "Final wins and losses"
                print "Wins: " + str(wins)
                print "Losses: " + str(losses)
                programLoop = False

main()
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate you helping me. I was wondering how come it only update the score if I select "yes" to replay and it doesn't update score when i select "no" for quitting the game. And how come it doesn't update the score - as in show score at the very Top? It still says "win = 0" "losses = 0" the only time the score updates is when i select 'yes' but it updates score under the "would you like to play again? select yes or no..." area

Comment: Sorry for all the questions >.<

Comment: Oh! I see. Thank you for the help! i really appreciate it! sorry for the trouble I am a total beginner x.x

Comment: Hi i wrote the algorithm but i feel as if its wrong since i didn't put the score counter because I'm not 100% sure how to add in score keeping into the algorithm. Just scared I'll screw up this algorithm @_@ So is the algorithm for main function wrong? here is my algorithm and i apologize for all the questions >.<

Comment: hmm how would i show u my algorithm? it seems to be too long for this comment box - still learning how to use this site aha

Comment: Hi, I just posted it just now :)

Comment: I also apologize for any trouble that I may have caused. Thanks!